Change initial version of HTMLmeta tags in React
I want to change contents of index.html meta tags. I created function which updates meta after initial html is loaded so when I try to paste a link in social media channels e.g slack, facebook, etc. It won't resolve title, description and image. It loads html meta before update.
`
useEffect(() => { if (!meta) return;

const title = meta.title || '';
const description = meta.description || '';

let imageUrl = '';
let imageAlt = '';
let mimeType = '';

if (meta.media) {
  imageUrl = `${apiUrl}${meta.media.url}`;
  imageAlt = meta.media.alt;
  mimeType = meta.media.mimeType;
}

updateMetaTags(title, description, imageUrl, imageAlt, mimeType);
}, [meta]);

//setting meta tags from updateMetaTags function using querySelector
updateMetaTags('og:title', title);
updateMetaTags('og:description', description);
updateMetaTags('og:image', imageUrl);
updateMetaTags('og:image:alt', imageAlt);
updateMetaTags('og:image:type', mimeType);

After this html is updated after I get api response but when I paste link result's coming from initial version of html. How can I resolve it?
`
